# error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type io.realm.RealmList

Tags: android, realm, kotlin, parceler

I'm programing a project by using Kotlin:

- **Kotlin version: 1.1.3-2**
- **Parcerler version 1.1.9**
- **Realm version 3.2.0**

I am using Parceler for FragmentArgs with RealmObjects and getting the following crash.
***Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type io.realm.RealmList***

1. My Class Job like this:

```
@Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = arrayOf(Job::class))
            open class Job(
                    @PrimaryKey open var tweetId: Long? = -1L,
                    open var text: String = "",
                    open var title: String = "",
                    open var longitude: Double? = null,
                    open var latitude: Double? = null,
                    open var link: String = "",
                @ParcelPropertyConverter(RealmStringListParcelConverter::class)
                    open var imageUrls: RealmList<RealmString>? = null
            ) : RealmObject()
```

2. The class RealmString looks like this:
   My class RealmString.kt like this:

```
@Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = arrayOf(RealmString::class))
                open class RealmString(
                        open var value: String = ""
                ) : RealmObject()
```

3. The class RealmListParcelConverter looks like this:

```
public class RealmListParcelConverter implements TypeRangeParcelConverter<RealmList<? extends RealmObject>, RealmList<? extends RealmObject>>
{
    private static final int NULL = -1;

    @Override
    public void toParcel(RealmList<? extends RealmObject> input, Parcel parcel)
    {
        parcel.writeInt(input == null ? NULL : input.size());
        if(input != null)
        {
            for(RealmObject item : input)
            {
                parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(item), 0);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RealmList fromParcel(Parcel parcel)
    {
        int       size = parcel.readInt();
        RealmList list = new RealmList();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Parcelable parcelable = parcel.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
            list.add((RealmObject) Parcels.unwrap(parcelable));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

I have tried add implementations = RealmStringRealmProxy and implementations = JobRealmProxy , still get the same issue.

### UPDATE 2

Update **Realm version** to **3.5.0** , still get the same issue.

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest version of Realm Java (3.5.0), are you still seeing the same behavior?

Comment: Why not concat the imageUrls into a single field, and split them apart in the getter?

Comment: @AviWarner yep still the same

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes i can do this but that is not a perfect solution for me. I want to use RealmList and that is a better way

Comment: `use RealmList and that is a better way` it's really not, but ok. Not sure what the error is though, maybe you need to use `RealmStringListParcelConverter::class.java`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thx for your advice however it's not working. If I use RealmStringListParcelConverter::class.java it'll show this error: **Typed inference failed** because of it required KClass not Class

Answer (score 1):

finally I got one solution for this answer. All you need is add `setter` in my model `Job`. I'll give my whole code here:

1. My Class Job like this:

```
@Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = arrayOf(Job::class))
            open class Job(
                    @PrimaryKey open var tweetId: Long? = -1L,
                    open var text: String = "",
                    open var title: String = "",
                    open var longitude: Double? = null,
                    open var latitude: Double? = null,
                    open var link: String = "",

            ) :RealmObject(){
@ParcelPropertyConverter(RealmStringListParcelConverter::class)
                        open var imageUrls: RealmList<RealmString>? = null set}
```

2. The class RealmString looks like this:
   My class RealmString.kt like this:

```
@Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = arrayOf(RealmString::class))
                open class RealmString(
                        open var value: String = ""
                ) : RealmObject()
```

3. The class RealmStringListParcelConverter looks like this:

```
   class RealmStringListParcelConverter : RealmListParcelConverter<RealmString>() {
    override fun itemToParcel(input: RealmString?, parcel: Parcel?) {
        parcel?.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(RealmString::class.java, input), 0)
    }

    override fun itemFromParcel(parcel: Parcel?): RealmString {
        return Parcels.unwrap(parcel?.readParcelable<Parcelable>(RealmString::class.java.classLoader))
    }
}
```